# How are inequalities spread over multiple lines to be read?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here's a basic question I've been avoiding. One often sees strings of equalities like these:

\begin{split}
A & = B\\
  & = C\\
\end{split}

Which can be read as either

$$A = B\\
B = C
$$

or

$$
A = B\\
A = C.
$$

But what about 
\begin{split}
A & < B\\
  & < C\,?\\
\end{split}

In this case

$$
A < B\\
B < C
$$

and

$$
A < B\\
A < C
$$

say two entirely different things. So what's the standard interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read those chains of inequalities as if they were all written on one line. They're on multiple lines only for typographic convenience.

The same is true of chains of equalities, but in that case the alternate reading just happens to be true.

Answer (score 3):

The equalities
\begin{align*}
A &= B \\
&= C
\end{align*}
are read as
$$ A = B = C,$$
and the inequalities
\begin{align*}
A &< B \\
&< C
\end{align*}
are read as
$$
A < B< C.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$A=B$$

$$=C$$

Means firstly $A=B$.
The $=C$ means $B=C$. But technically, if $A=B$, and $B=C$, we can also read as $A=C$

$$A<B$$
$$<C$$

This means $A<B$ first of all. As said above, $B<C$. But if $A<B$ and $B<C$, then we must have $A<B<C$ combining it all together.

Suppose you want to prove that for $f(x)=x^2$, that $2<f(2)$

Well, here is how you do it:

$$f(2)=(2)^2$$

$$=4$$

$$\text{ we are saying 2^2 = 4, and equivalently that f(2) =4}$$

$$>2$$

$$\text{we are saying 4 > 2, or equivalently, 2^2 > 4, or equivalently, f(2) > 2}$$

$$\therefore 2<f(2)$$